# Help with algebraic manipulation to prove that $\Omega (M)$ constructed from $\Omega^1 (M)$ forms an algebra over $C^\infty (M)$

Tags: differential-geometry, multilinear-algebra

In Baez´s Gauge Theories, Knots and Gravity he states that the differential forms on a n dimensional manifold M, $\Omega (M) = {\bigoplus}_p  \Omega^p (M)$, constructed from $\Omega^1(M)$ and the wedge product between 1-forms is indeed an algebra over $C^\infty (M)$ i.e., that for $\omega, \mu, \nu \in \Omega (M)$ and $f,g \in C^\infty (M)$ we have the 9 properties of an algebra:

1. $\omega + \mu = \mu + \omega$
2. $\omega + (\mu + \nu) = (\omega + \mu) + \nu$
3. $\omega \wedge (\mu \wedge \nu) = (\omega \wedge \mu)\wedge \nu$ , etc.

My question is, for example, if I want to prove properties 1 and 3, because they are differential forms, do I need to feed them a vector field to prove the equalities? and it still confuses me how do I prove the properties if $\omega, \mu, \nu \in \Omega (M)$ are not p-forms with a given p, with $0 \leq p \leq n$ ?

More concretly, my first guess to prove property 1 is to note that we can write the forms as $$\omega= \sum_{{i}_1...{i}_p =1}^{n} {\omega}_{{i}_1...{i}_p} dx^{{i}_1} \wedge...\wedge dx^{{i}_p}$$ $$\mu= \sum_{{i}_1...{i}_p =1}^{n} {\mu}_{{i}_1...{i}_p} dx^{{i}_1} \wedge...\wedge dx^{{i}_p}$$ 
so $\omega+\mu = \sum_{{i}_1...{i}_p =1}^{n} {\omega}_{{i}_1...{i}_p} dx^{{i}_1} \wedge...\wedge dx^{{i}_p} + \sum_{{i}_1...{i}_p =1}^{n} {\mu}_{{i}_1...{i}_p} dx^{{i}_1} \wedge...\wedge dx^{{i}_p} = \sum_{{i}_1...{i}_p =1}^{n} {\mu}_{{i}_1...{i}_p} dx^{{i}_1} \wedge...\wedge dx^{{i}_p} +\sum_{{i}_1...{i}_p =1}^{n} {\omega}_{{i}_1...{i}_p} dx^{{i}_1} \wedge...\wedge dx^{{i}_p} = \mu + \omega$ am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could feed the forms appropriate $p$-tuples of tangent vectors to prove those properties. The fact that $p$ is not given explicitly simply indicates these properties hold across all appropriate degrees. I'm not sure your last equation is anything more than changing notation, I wouldn't consider it a proof unless you already have other results to which I'm unaware.

I suppose the base of your question is really how to construct the exterior algebra. The long, very concrete, way is to begin by defining the tensor product:
$$ (T \otimes S)(x,y) = T(x)S(y) $$
Then use that to build the wedge:
$$ T \wedge S = T \otimes S - S \otimes T $$
In this view you get to prove some properties of the wedge-product as derived from the tensor product. In particular, properties 1 and 3 follow for $\wedge$ because they're true for $\otimes$ and the properties filter nicely through the construction:
$$ T_1 \wedge T_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge T_k = \sum_{\sigma} sgn(\sigma) T_{\sigma(1)} \otimes T_{\sigma(2)} \otimes \cdots \otimes T_{\sigma(k)} $$

The better way to construct the algebra is by taking a quotient and using a universal property. In that way of thinking these properties are essentially automatic and characterize what makes the exterior algebra what it is. I suspect you'll find the universal construction if you start hunting through the posts linked to your post.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to avoid using Tensors. In the referenced book, Baez constructs the exterior algebra of wedge products of a Vector Space $\Lambda V = {\bigoplus}_p \Lambda ^p V$ being the algebra generated by $V$ with the relations $v \wedge w = -w \wedge v$ for all $v,w \in V$ and then copying the construction of $\Lambda V$, with the smoooth functions $C^\infty (M)$ taking the place of real numbers and the 1-forms $\Omega ^1 (M)$ taking he place of the vector space $V$.

Comment: @aortizmena the statement "Baez constructs the exterior algebra of wedge products of a Vector Space...being the algebra generated by V  with the relations $v\wedge  w=−w\wedge v$ ..." is precisely the "taking a quotient and using a universal property" James S.Cook was talking about. Here the quotient is between the free algebra generated by any basis $\{e_{\bullet}\}$ of $V$ and the two sided ideal generated by the relations $e_{i}e_{j}+e_{j}e_{i}$ (I hid the tensor product $\otimes$ as a product $\cdot$). Please let me know if you need more details.